Only get subsection of Exception
In Python, I'm persisting some errors to a database.
I want to be able to group these errors by their error details.
However, currently, I am persisting the exception itself as follows:
try:
   # logic
except Exception as e:
   persist(e) # this just does an insert of e

This is resulting in a DB table like this:



name
failure_reason




name1
001003 (42000): 01b51169-0409-e03e-0075-e9028c3cc103: SQL compilation error:\n syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'.


name1
001003 (42000): 01b5116c-0409-e03e-0075-e9028c3cf86b: SQL compilation error:\n syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'.


name2
001003 (42000): 02b6117h-9876-e03f-0075-e9028c2ayhwb: SQL compilation error:\n syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'.



As you can see, when I persist the Exception itself, it contains a UUID which stops me from easily grouping on the error.
I've tried using the following, but what I want is something that will give me just SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'.
e.__class__.__name__
str(e)
repr(e)
traceback.format_exc()

... this includes the UUID too.

You could just use a regexp that matches UUIDs to "redact" them out of your failure_reason before inserting:
import re

uuid_re = re.compile(r"[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}", re.IGNORECASE)


def redact_failure_reason(s: str) -> str:
    return uuid_re.sub("<UUID>", s)


redacted_failure_reason = redact_failure_reason(
    "001003 (42000): 01b51169-0409-e03e-0075-e9028c3cc103: "
    "SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'."
)

print(redacted_failure_reason)

prints out
001003 (42000): <UUID>: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'.


Great solution to the question I posted - my fault, but my question didn't contain all the relevant information (e.g some rows don't follow this patter: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'xyz' (0)"). I was hoping for a e. method of getting a solution (e.g high level error details from the Exception itself, but its my fault for not including the other rows in the Q

That would depend entirely on the thing emitting the exception. If the exception only contains the message string, there's not much more you can do.

You can use a little bit of string manipulation to throw away the leading UUID etc. and just compare the remainder. If the prefix always has a length of 54 characters (as is the case in the sample data you show), you can do
error_full = """001003 (42000): 01b51169-0409-e03e-0075-e9028c3cc103: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'."""

error_short = error_full[53:]
print(error_short)

# SQL compilation error:
# syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'.

A slightly more advanced way would be to use the colons separating the fields. The idea is to split the string on a colon and joining the wanted items of the resulting list.
Use the following code to throw the first two fields out:
error_full = """001003 (42000): 01b51169-0409-e03e-0075-e9028c3cc103: SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'."""

error_short = ''.join(error.split(':', maxsplit=2)[2:]).strip()
print(error_short)

# SQL compilation error
# syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'seelect'.


Hello anonymous downvoter, did you find an error in my answer? Are my explanations bad? Is my whole idea flawed? Please leave a comment and I'll try to improve my answer. Thank you.
